# Javascript: how to trigger a backspace keypress when pressing enter key in conteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Due to some complicated reason, When user press enter key in contenteditable div, I **have to** hard code to imitate the normal behavior of changing lines, my attempt was that when enter key is pressed, first, two br tags then created (works fine)and then second, delete last br by imitating user's pressing on backspace (works not fine).

My attempt is below, which fails to imitate user's backspace keypress at the caret position.

html:

```
<div id="hithere" style="border:1px solid black" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$('div[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {

                 document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, ' <br><br>');
                     $(function() {
                     var bre = $.Event('keypress');
                        bre.keyCode= 8; // enter
                    document.trigger(bre);
                    });
    }

    //   // prevent the default behaviour of return key pressed
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You know this seems like an unlikely bodge... You write "__have to__" - does that mean you can't alter the code that leads you to believe this? And I still don't know why you create two breaks if you only want one?

Comment: No I can't alter the method.. :(

Comment: Care to tell us why you create two `<br>´s when you need only one?

Comment: In your jsfiddle the new line break is created by using div tag not br, this is why it looks fine to you, because the whole code doesn't work at all on your JSfiddle somehow...the br part works fine on my server though.

Comment: @RachelGallen Incidentally, your code also works if you remove it completely, btw :P https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/pjuf6zrc/1/ (i.e. I assume that there is a contextual problem somewhere, otherwise this question wouldn't likely come up) ...I just wish we knew more about the context here :D

Comment: @BenPhilipp so it does! what is the nature of the problem then?? Yes context (or a bit of knowledge on his part) would be helpful

Comment: I think since I'm not returning true, we can assume that the <br /> created was indeed not the standard execution of the enter keypress event - I thought that might help in what ever mysterious situations we're dealing with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the problem which you probably ran into but didn't write about:
The `<br />` is inserted, but when the user continues typing, the text gets inserted above the break.

You can insert the break as Text instead, using the two components \r and \n (Carriage Return and New Line)

```
document.execCommand('insertText', false, '\r\n');
```

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/6o5ao1bm/1/

Comment: Also, only return false if the key was enter. ...If you need to delete something, just use `document.execCommand('delete');`

Comment: yours is also exactly the same when the js is commented out

Comment: @BenPhilipp Thanks a lot, this part of the problem solved,  Is there something like document.execCommand('pressUpArrowKey')?